# why Map.Entry is not array?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

What would have happened if Map.Entry was Map.Entry [] and not list in hashMap? I just want to understand why bucket is list and not array implementation in hashmap java.

Comment: an array would have to be re-sized each time you add an element to it.  Lists are much more dynamic

Comment: was it only reason, i mean to find element from list would have to go each and every node.

Comment: Barring an official document talking about this design decision somewhere, answers to this question are going to be entirely opinion based

Comment: I don't have Java 8 here at work, but in 7 the data in a `HashMap` *is* an array: `transient Entry<K,V>[] table;`

Comment: @azurefrog Each Entry in the array is/was actually a linked list. The question appears to ask about this linked list.

Comment: where exactly did you see `Map.Entry` list ? Is it HashMap ? Also your version would help. As far as I know it's just an Entry[]

Comment: @Radiodef Ah, I misunderstood the OP's question then, I thought he was talking about the `HashMap` backing array.

Comment: Map.Entry class has next pointer, is my understanding correct?.

Comment: The next pointer is to deal with hashing collisions.  This allows an arbitrary number of `Entry`s to be stored in a given hash bucket.

Comment: how next pointer is used to detect hash collision?. I think it is done just by flipping lower bits of hash code.

Comment: @Brijesh It's not used to detect a hash collision, but is used when you create an `Entry` for any given index in the backing array. The new `Entry` is created with its `next` pointing at the previous entry (which could be `null`), and then that index populated with the new `Entry`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're talking about the `LinkedList` in each bucket entry.

Let's say it's an Array, when you add an element to that bucket you have to create an array of some definite size say 10, here you're already allocating memory for 10 entries (of course it's not too much) but the elements in that array are added based on the elements having same `hashcode()` but different `equals()`.
What if there are only 2 elements in that bucket but we reserved space for 10,  you may end up having sparsely filled arrays.

Also you've to deal with re-sizing of these bucket arrays as long as you add elements having same hashcode. And when you need to deal with re-sizing, you usually maintain a counter to check if the number of elements reaches the current array size, create a bigger array, copy all these elements and you have to all these things in a single `put` call to Map :) The main advantage of arrays is random access, but when you try to `get` some element from array, it doesn't know which one has matching `equals()`, so it'll traverse through all the elements of that array loosing the very advantage of arrays.

But if you use a `LinkedList`, you just keep adding elements, no need to create/re-size an array. Also if you notice, one smart thing they're doing while adding elements to `LinkedList` is they don't traverse through the entire list to find the last element. They create a new `Entry` object whose next element is pointing to the existing element stored in bucket index and update the bucket index to point to this new element, that way they don't have to traverse the list every time you add a new element. So it's a gain in memory and speed :)

One more update in jdk8 is that this `LinkedList` implementation in changed to a `Tree` once it reaches a threshold(8). This is to facilitate faster look ups, so instead of traversing through all the elements to `get` some element in O(n) (linear) time, it's now O(logn)

Comment: For better understanding of HashMap implementation, read [this](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2013/08/hashing-how-hash-map-works-in-java-or.html)

Comment: Noticeably, hardcoded singly-linked lists are really, really efficient for very small n, like 0, 1, or 2 -- which is what you expect for hash table buckets.

Comment: I agree it is the sparse arrays and conserving space argument.

Answer (score 1):

Well it would simply have been more difficult to handle, for example re-sizing.

If you look at the code of `List` classes, you will find out that at the base, most of them are just `Array` with methods to handle the array easier for developers.

Comment: Yeah i agree with List implementation but Map.Entry has next pointer which which will point to next location in memory and not continuous memory block

Comment: Well not all lists are just Array wrappers.. like linkedlist

Comment: @Brijesh The next pointer doesn't point to the next location in memory, it points to the previous `Entry` that lived at a given index in the backing array at the time that you create a new `Entry` for that index.

Comment: @azurefrog as per my understanding, entry is array objects but internally each bucket can have list of objects with same hashcode, which is i mean to say list. So it has pointer which points to next location. Is my understanding correct?.

Comment: `Entry` is itself a singly linked list which has 4 properties - key, value, hashcode and a `next` property which is another `Entry` object, so to put it simply, HashMap is an Array of LinkedLists :)

Answer (score 1):

This below mentioned difference will help you understand why not `Map.Entry[]`

Main consideration is ***SIZE(point no 2)*** but there are other reasons too

**Lists(Linked List in this case) are preferable over arrays when:**

1. You need constant-time insertions/deletions from the list (such as
   in real-time computing where time predictability is absolutely
   critical)
2. **You don't know how many items will be in the list**. With arrays,
   you may need to re-declare and copy memory if the array grows too
   big
3. you don't need random access to any elements

**Arrays are preferable when:**

1. you need indexed/random access to elements
2. you know the number of elements in the array ahead of time so that
   you can allocate the correct amount of memory for the array
3. Arrays have O(1) random access, but are **really expensive** to **add**
   stuff onto or **remove** stuff from.

[More Reasons are here , Please Help yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist/24607151#24607151)